# Add more than one event Listener to react-native AppState

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add two `AppState` eventListeners to an app, but it seems like the seconde one is overriding the first.

Is there any way to use both eventListeners?

Comment: If I add multiple they do seem to both fire but unclear if this is a bad idea as if one unmounts it will remove all change handlers?

Comment: I don't know about that, I ended using one and storing variables that will determine the behavior when the app is active again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, events can have multiple listeners. That is the whole point of the event architecture.

Always make sure your events are in a `useEffect` and the events are removed after unloading.